Xamarin forms iOS Xam.Plugin.Media Only one operation can be active at a time Error even when multitap is preveted
I am facing an issue in Xamarin forms iOS in release.
Xam.Plugin.Media gives an error "Only one operation can be active at a time" in some physical devices and for released version only.
I already have prevented multitap on button which initiates the camera functionality.
Here is the code for camera work.
void CapturePhoto_View(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        imgBtnCaptureProfilePhoto_ViewMode.IsEnabled = false;
        ProfilePhotoCapture(true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        imgBtnCaptureProfilePhoto_ViewMode.IsEnabled = true;
        Common_Functions.ShowToast(ex, ex.Message);
    }
}


async void ProfilePhotoCapture(bool isForView)
{
    try
    {
        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
        {
            imgBtnCaptureProfilePhoto_ViewMode.IsEnabled = true;
            Common_Functions.ShowToast(new Exception(NoCamaraMessage), NoCamaraMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            var result = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Camera>();
            if (result == PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
                {
                    Directory = "ProfilePhoto",
                    SaveToAlbum = false,
                    CustomPhotoSize = 15,
                    CompressionQuality = 30,
                    DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Front,
                    Name = "profiePhoto.jpg",
                    PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium,
                    MaxWidthHeight = 600,
                });
                if (file != null)
                {
                    sfImgProfileView.ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => file.GetStream());
                    imgBtnCaptureProfilePhoto_ViewMode.IsEnabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    imgBtnCaptureProfilePhoto_ViewMode.IsEnabled = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Common_Functions.ShowToast(null, "Please enable camera permission");
                DependencyService.Get<IAppSettingsHelper>().OpenAppSettings();
                imgBtnCaptureProfilePhoto_ViewMode.IsEnabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        imgBtnCaptureProfilePhoto_ViewMode.IsEnabled = true;
        Common_Functions.ShowToast(ex, ex.Message);
    }
}

Error:
ErrorStackTrace:  at Plugin.Media.MediaImplementation.GetMediaAsync (UIKit.UIImagePickerControllerSourceType sourceType, System.String mediaType, Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions options, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) <0x102eadcb0 + 0x00600> in <2b37f663ea3145849e7620d599244131#b309e6125e885e6e83ace80a389d2a2b>:0 
  at Plugin.Media.MediaImplementation.TakePhotoAsync (Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions options, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) <0x102ebb290 + 0x0041f> in <2b37f663ea3145849e7620d599244131#b309e6125e885e6e83ace80a389d2a2b>:0 
  at Clipboard2.Views.BedSideDocument.PatientImageCapture.AddPhoto (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) <0x10299cd60 + 0x00637> in <0c4299026809489eb05d613373a06f3b#b309e6125e885e6e83ace80a389d2a2b>:0 

Any Solutions to prevent this error?
I have prevented multi tap on button which initiate the camera functionality
